# How to fix "maya standalone could not be found" error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya, mayavi, maya-api

I'm trying to import `maya.standalone` in Python(IDLE). I declared the environment variable but still I'm getting the error below.

`import maya.standalone ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Here's my code:

import os,sys from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui,uic

```
os.environ["MAYA_LOCATION"] = "C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014" 
os.environ["PYTHONHOME"]    = "C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014\\Python" 
os.environ["PATH"] = "C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014\\bin;" + os.environ["PATH"]

sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014\\bin") 
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014\\bin\\python27.zip") 
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014\\Python") 
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014\\Python\\DLLs") 
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014\\Python\\lib") 
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014\\Python\\lib\\site-packages") 
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\maya")


import maya.standalone 
maya.standalone.initialize(name='python')
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

You have to import this module with mayapy instead of python.
Add to your path "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\bin;"

Then in a windows command, type :

```
mayapy
import maya.standalone
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but still is not working, if u have code please give me.

Comment: When I came to maya standalone, I follwed this post : http://www.toadstorm.com/blog/?p=136
If you type mayapy in command line, is it working ?